# Easy reverse proxy for serving images over ssl

Tags: https, gmail, reverse-proxy, mixed-content

I created a simple web-based email client like gmail. I want to display images, but in order to do it with my ssl site, I need all images served over ssl (otherwise I get "mixed-content" warnings). So I need a reverse proxy like gmail has to serve those images.

I will rewrite all image urls in the email to point at the reverse proxy. For example:

My reverse proxy is https://myreverseproxy.com

original image url http://stuff.com/image1.jpg

I will rewrite the url to be https://myreverseproxy.com?image-url=http://stuff.com/image1.jpg

When the reverse proxy gets the request "https://myreverseproxy.com?image-url=http://stuff.com/image1.jpg" it will get the original image from the query parameter image-url (http://stuff.com/image1.jpg), fetch the image, and return it to the requester of https://myreverseproxy.com?image-url=http://stuff.com/image1.jpg.

Are there any services that do this out of the box? Could I write one that's simple? Are there any libraries or solutions already for this that I could just install somewhere?

I'm open to any language and any platform...I just want this issue resolved.

Comment: FYI, you can set up a web server, e.g. Apache or nginx as a reverse proxy. If you need more flexibility, use HAProxy. Guides for all these can be easily found. Run them separately from your application, and add session/token authentication for security.

Comment: As a side note - you may think about embedding image into email instead of using an image server, most email clients, if not all of them, would block the image link by default, unless the receipt whitelist the sender. Also, if emails are sending to external parties, this approach will save your cost on bandwidth if they read the email for more than once.

Comment: Thanks @Hang. This is only for incoming emails (originating outside my system). When we send out emails, we will swap the image urls back to their original so that no one outside is hitting our reverse proxy. In fact we will lock it down by IP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest the same thing as Tudor: a proxy written in node.

However, I would advise using a more broadly used and tested library such as [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy). It is *really* simple to setup, and will achieve what you need in less than 20 lines of code.

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy')

httpProxy.createServer({
  target: {
    host: 'stuff.com',
    port: 80
  },
  ssl: {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl-key.pem', 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl-cert.pem', 'utf8')
  }
}).listen(443);
```

If a client then accesses **https://reverseproxy.com/image.png**, the process would go as follows

[image]

I have assumed in this schema that the reverse proxy runs on a different server as the webserver serving the images, but this does not have to be the case. If they both run on the same server, just use `host: 'localhost'` in the `target` section.

--

Just in case you are not familiar with Node, here's what you need to do in order to quickly run this setup.

- Install Node
- Create a new file containing the code in **yourprojectpath/index.js**
- Generate a package.json file by running `npm init` in your project's directory
- Run `npm install --save http-proxy` to install the `http-proxy` library and be able to use it in the code

You should now be able to run the reverse proxy by running

```
node index.js
```

If you are planning on using this in production, I highly recommend you take a look at [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2). It is a process manager for node which basically ensures that your application is *always* running, no matter what. In particular, it will restart it if any kind of exception is thrown from the application and would have caused it to terminate.

Installation:

```
npm install -g pm2
```

Usage:

```
pm2 start index.js
```

A few more notes:

- make sure that your `.pem` files have appropriate permissions and owner. `chmod 400` is usually a good option (only readable by owner). The user running the Node application should be able to read them, though.
- if your server runs behind a (software or hardware) firewall, you may need to open your port 443 to incoming traffic
- depending on your SSL certificate provider, you might need to convert the files it will provide you to the PEM format
- if needed, node-http-proxy supports [additional options](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy#options) such as adding headers when a request is proxied
- the script I presented above assumes you have `ssl-key.pem` and `ssl-cert.pem` in the same directory as it

Hope that helps! And just ask if something looks unclear to you

Comment: thank you! "I have assumed in this schema that the reverse proxy runs on a different server as the webserver serving the images" Yes that is the case. In fact these images will come from all over the web. I'm using the reverse proxy to retrieve http hosted images over https so that my web email client won't complain about mixed content (see my question). Will this still work?

Comment: I plan to host this in azure...any gotchas or things I should be aware of?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to create self-signed certificates, if you don't have any

[Nodejitsu docs](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server)

Now for the code, which is written in node.js:

[HTTPS proxy](https://gist.github.com/tudorilisoi/2cad7b12aeb88515e5e9bdb7cb8e1fa0)

...and a screenshot :)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks! We have purchased certs and will need one more for this subdomain. So that code is an https proxy written in node? Wow...I will take a look!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easily with nginx. Btw, it can be done like you ask and it is also possible to make urls exact same like origin url. For example cdn.xxx.com/img.jpg - www.xxx.com/img.jpg.

Answer (score -1):

Richard, You can resolve the issue of mixed content easily by enabling CORS in nginx config file, here is a example http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html. In this it is alllowing cors for everyone, you can set for a particular domain or ip, you need to look in more details.